# Gnuplot cannot read ansi-file

Tags: gnuplot

Gnuplot tells me:

> warning: Skipping unreadable file 'kalibrierung.txt'"
>   (kalibrierung.txt is my data file)

I've been using gnuplot for nearly a year, but after I reinstalled my Windows 7 64 bit, it won't read any data files anymore.

Here is what I checked already:

- I tried UTF8 and ANSI
- The data file really only contains data
- The path is right, and since it tells me that my file is not readable it seems to find it.
- Google of course: I found all kinds of solutions there, but not for my problem
- I tried a different data file, looking like this:

> 1 2
>
> 3 4
>
> 5 6

**Edit**: Tried a new installation, but no change.

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your gnuplot script or commands?

Comment: I found the solution..
since I can't aswere my own question yet, I wanted to do an edit instead, but you were faster :)

sorry that I bothered. A very kind friend of mine helped me out at 3:35 in the moring, local time. I forgot to change the directory (file -> Change Directory ...), which he told me to check by typing in 'pwd'. Hope this helps other desperate people, too.

best wishes

thanks a lot anyways, btw how do make line breaks without blank lines here?

Comment: @user3810699 You should be able to answer your own question; I don't recall there being a rep limit for that. And you can end each line with two spaces to create a line break. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for more formatting guidelines.

Comment: I get the following message. seems legit:

"Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 7/7/2014 8:55:48 AM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."